# SQL change column type depending on other table [nvarchar to int(FK)]

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a database a few months ago and actually, the architecture is awful. Now, I have almost 2 million records and because I didn't build the database correctly at the beginning, the requests are very long.
Below the two tables concerned:

**TableA:**

```
id (PK, int)  
category (nvarchar)  
date (datetime)
```

**TableB**

```
id (PK, int)  
category (nvarchar)
```

I would like to change the category column to "int" and create a relationship between the tables (FK). See below:

**TableA:**

```
id (PK, int)  
category (FK, int)  
date (datetime)
```

**Keys: PK_TableA, FK_TableB**

I don't ask the solution but some tips to build the script to do that:
- change the column
- for each record,
look at the category > take the id > replace the category name (string) by the id(int)

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Are you certain that the column only has numeric data?  If you can tolerate it, just working around this when you query might be an option here.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: @jarlh  Microsoft SQL Server, wrong tag my bad.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can start from something like this.
At the end, after your checks (anyway backup your table before doing update), you can delete CATEGORY column from tableA and (if you want) rename column CATEGORY_ID.
If you want, before starting, you can do a check for later use (see at the end):

```
SELECT CATEGORY, COUNT(*) AS RC
FROM TABLEA
GROUP BY CATEGORY;
```

**Sample script**

```
CREATE TABLE TABLEA (ID INT, CATEGORY VARCHAR(20), DATE_A DATETIME);


CREATE TABLE TABLEB (ID INT, CATEGORY VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES (1,'abc', GETDATE());
INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES (2,'cde', GETDATE());
INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES (3,'cde', GETDATE());
INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES (4,'abc', GETDATE());
INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES (5,'abc', GETDATE());
INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES (6,'fgh', GETDATE());
INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES (7,'zzz', GETDATE());

INSERT INTO TABLEB VALUES (100,'abc');
INSERT INTO TABLEB VALUES (200,'cde');
INSERT INTO TABLEB VALUES (300,'fgh');


SELECT * FROM TABLEA;

ALTER TABLE TABLEA ADD CATEGORY_ID INT;

UPDATE A SET CATEGORY_ID = B.ID
FROM TABLEA A 
LEFT JOIN TABLEB B ON A.CATEGORY = B.CATEGORY;


--CREATE INDEX TABLEA_CATID ON TABLEA (CATEGORY_ID);

SELECT CATEGORY_ID, COUNT(*) AS RC
FROM TABLEA
GROUP BY CATEGORY_ID;
```

For semplicity, I didn't add PK (but as you know they are "necessary").
I suggest to define FK constraint on TABLEA for CATEGORY_ID.

Comment: Cheers mate, that's a good start. I know what I have to do now.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at how you named your columns I'd say that you want a new column categoryid (FK, int) instead of the category (nvarchar) in TableA.

The naive way of getting this would be to create a new column with a nullable property, populate it, set the constraint, remove the nullable property and last remove the category (varchar) column. If you cannot change the column name you need to add a few extra steps to switch out the columns.

Since you already have two million rows you are probaly better of creating a new table (TableC), populating it and swichting out TableA with TableC (drop/rename TableA, rename TableC TableA).

TableC:

```
id (PK, int)  
categoryid (FK, int)  
date (datetime)
```

You are usually better off making new tables and switching out the old one when dealing with tables with large amounts of rows.

Regards Martin

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used the code provided by @etsa (with some changes) and I created a new table instead of add/rename the column. Now, I'm doing some test to create a script. So I've already done what you advise but thanks :)